# WKWEbView Loading URL and evaluate

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, wkwebview, evaluatejavascript

I want to access javascript file store properties. How can I do that?

I want to fetch user ID. and also I want to call a function which will set push token to server. any suggestion?
for example:

```
func getProfileUserIDFromJavaScript() {
        let javascript = "GameState.Profile.Uid()"
        webView.evaluateJavaScript(javascript) { (result, error) in
            if let uID = result as? String {
                // Use the adUnitId obtained from JavaScript
                print("User ID: \(uID)")
                self.userID = uID
            } else {
                print("Error obtaining User ID: \(error?.localizedDescription ?? "Unknown error")")
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Call function with """ function """ Solved my problem.

I searched this on many websites but finally I found this which works well for me.